# Java Servlet: performance issue

Tags: java, performance, servlets, weblogic

I hava written a simple servlet which contains only the service methode(the code below). I run a test under weblogic server (version 10.3.6) and I executed a load tests using Gatling.
But I was surprised by a great variation of time response with peaks as mentioned in the figure (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP2Fz.png): for example, the selected peak mention 99% of threads have a 27 ms as a time response and only 1% of threads have time response equal to 320ms.

Servlet code:

```
@Override
   public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            String responseMessage = "hello world";
            // the message (which is the route)
            response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(200);
            response.setContentLength(2);
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(responseMessage.getBytes());         
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to understand the cause of the peaks and who to decrease max values

Comment: You may try to profile your `service` method first, while you test it with Gatling. If the execution time seems constant within that, then the issue will probably be with Weblogic and/or its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> 1% of threads have time response equal to 320ms

No. The 99th percentile being 27ms and your max being 320mx means that 1% of your response times are between those two values. As you don't know the distribution there, you can't tell if those are mostly on the lower or the upper side.

> I was surprised by a great variation of time response

An application involves many physical components that are usually not dedicated to your usage but shared with others (network, CPU, etc), so hiccups are bound to happen.

What you want is to keep their probability low.

So now we're talking stats. You'd need to have enough values so that your sample is statistically significant, and know what your 99.9th and 99.99th percentiles are so you'd really know how your hiccups look like. Gatling standard report don't give you, you'd have to compute them from the data in the simulation.log file.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your response. I have profile the application and analyse log files especially for garbage collector pause, but I did not find any reason for this peak. May be as you said it may be related to physical components.